# What is the difference between count and select('DISTINCT COUNT(xxx)') in ActiveRecord?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have two queries that are similar:

```
StoreQuery.group(:location).count(:name)
```

vs

```
StoreQuery.group(:location).select('DISTINCT COUNT(name)')
```

I was expecting the results to be exactly the same but they're not. What is the difference between the two?

Answer (score 1):

The difference is that the first query counts all names, and the second query counts unique names, ignoring duplicates.  They will return different numbers if you have some names listed more than once.

Answer (score 0):

With this sample data

```
id | name | location |
---+------+----------+ 
1  | NULL | US
2  | A    | UK
3  | A    | UK
4  | B    | AUS
```

Let check the generated queries the results

**1st query**

```
StoreQuery.group(:location).count(:name)
```

Generated query:

```
SELECT location, COUNT(name) AS count FROM store_queries GROUP BY location
```

Result:

```
{US => 0, UK => 2, AUS => 1}
```

**2nd query**

```
StoreQuery.group(:location).select('DISTINCT COUNT(name)')
```

Generated query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(name) FROM store_queries GROUP BY location
```

Result:

```
ActiveRecord::Relation [StoreQuery count: 0, StoreQuery count: 1, StoreQuery count: 1]
# Mean {US => 0, UK => 1, AUS => 1}
```

So the differences will be:

```
                 |1st query | 2nd query |
                 |----------+-----------+
# returned fields|    2     |    1      |
     distinction |    no    |    yes    |
```

Btw, rails supports this:

```
StoreQuery.group(:location).count(:name, distinct: true)
```